# Copying contents of a specific folder with SVN

Tags: svn

I am having difficulty copying the contents of one subversion folder into another folder.    For example lets say i have:

```
https://svn_server.com/trunk/a
and...
https://svn_server.com/trunk/b
```

When i use the copy command like this:

`svn cp https://svn_server.com/trunk/a https://svn_server.com/trunk/b`

It works but it results in /trunk/b/a.  I simply want to duplicate the contents of /trunk/a into /trunk/b and ignore the parent folder.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is already some data in folder B, right?

I think that you don't need to use `svn copy` in this case because what you want is to *replace* data in folder B with data from folder A or merge these directories. You could checkout a working copy of trunk and copy contents from A to B. Add new files with `svn add` if necessary, review your changes and commit.